# Spring Boot 3: Can't set logging.pattern.console in application.yaml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to add a "correlation-id" to the logs that are written by my Spring-Boot application.

For that I've taken the [spring-boot logback default value](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml#L8) and added it to my application.yaml, which looks like this:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: ${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:-%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}
```

But now my application isn't starting anymore and fails with:

> Could not copy file '/my-project/src/main/resources/config/application.yaml' to '/my-project/build/resources/main/config/application.yaml'.
> Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
> SimpleTemplateScript62.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: '(' @ line 1, column 10.
> out.print("""spring:

- Putting "" around the pattern doesn't help
- replacing ":-" with ":" doesn't make a difference
- Removing all the variables (and putting "" around the pattern) works
- Setting the pattern as an environment variable works too

Is there something missing in my approach? I would prefer to have this change in my application.yaml instead of an environment variable so that not everyone needs to configure it locally to have the same log output as it is expected on production.

I'm using Spring-Boot 3.0.2 with gradle 7.6